# Problem with jQuery in IE8 with Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

I recently aquired an old website (we're talking tables, image maps, you name it).

I was asked to make an old link to a Flash gallery into a lightbox. I simply used a `javascript: openLightbox()` on the gallery link (top right corner). I know, I know, but it doesn't seem out of place on *this* site.

Anyway, I also include a JavaScript file scripts.js, which

- Includes jQuery and CSS files for [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).
- Use AJAX to get some JSON of image filenames
- Create a hidden unordered list on the page with links to the images from JSON
- Attach the fancybox method to these images

Then, on the `openLightbox()` I simply call the `click()` function on the first link.

Nice and easy, I thought. It worked like a charm in Firefox. Then my arch nemesis decided it didn't want to play ball. That's IE7/8.

I've had the IE8 Developer Tools out for a while but haven't been able to figure it out.
The only error I'm getting is "v is null or not an object" which is referencing the minified/packed jQuery code on Google's CDN. Obviously that's not the problem, so does anyone have any idea what is wrong here?

Here is a link to the page: http://edgewaterterraces.com.au/

Also...

- [script.js file](http://edgewaterterraces.com.au/scripts.js)

Thank you very much for your time.

**UPDATE**

Wow, it seems to work on [this page](http://edgewaterterraces.com.au/location.html). What gives?

Comment: I suggest you use an unminified version of jQuery while developing - it'll help you debug better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are embedding both jquery and script.js twice on the front page.

Once in line 12, once in line 27.

Comment: Ah! There was a tonne of HTML files, so I wrote a PHP script to insert jQuery into all of them. Must of accidentally
 ran it twice. Thanks!