# Images are overflowing their container in IE8 with Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

In a sort of follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241615/problem-with-jquery-in-ie8-with-fancybox), I have another problem in IE8.

When clicking the gallery and the lightbox appears, the images are overflowing their containing element (by the looks of things).

[image: IE8]
<sub>(source: [alexanderdickson.com](http://alexanderdickson.com/hosted/stackoverflow.com/ie8-fancybox.png))</sub>

Has anyone ever experienced this before? Of course, the good guys (Firefox/Safari/etc) display it perfectly.

How do I fix this?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Should I just got with a new Lightbox?

Comment: Is it happening to all the images or just a few?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clon). Not only does it work, but it provides a much better API. I could skip all my hidden link building and triggering, I passed the array of filepaths straight in and it worked great cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always just a tiny bit around the borders, it'd be a quick and dirty fix to just add `overflow: hidden` to the fancybox container.

Comment: Except then I'll lose some of the image, and by the looks of things, the white border too.

Answer (score 0):

Set the DOCTYPE, for example xHTML1.1 Transitional for the document and the problem will be solved. Or enable X-Compability mode.