# Fancybox - Image is overflowing off right side of lightbox

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, fancybox, ruby-on-rails-4

Looks like this question has been asked before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241767/967668), but the asker solved his own question by switching to prettyPhoto. I'd prefer to figure out why this is happening, just to understand, but I will switch if there doesn't seem to be a solution. There is also setting `overflow:hidden`, as noted in one of the answers, but I'm wondering if I can't just resize the box, instead of cutting off my images.

I am using fancybox 1.3.4 with the patch as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14344290/967668) stackoverflow article.

All the files I'm using (css, js, images) that come with the fancybox zip, are in the asset pipeline, and are unchanged, other than changing the image paths in the css file in order to use the images properly in rails' asset pipeline, using the rails image-url helper. I can post the css, but I do not believe it will be helpful (I could be wrong). I'm using the jQuery that comes with rails 4.

DOCTYPE is html.

My application.js file looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.easing-1.3.pack
//= require jquery.fancybox-1.3.4

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.image-gallery").fancybox({
    'width': 640,
    'height':480,
    'autoScale':true,
    'autoDimensions':false
  });
});
```

However, the images I've put into my lightbox gallery are overflowing off of the right side of the lightbox. You can see what I am talking about on firefox 25, [here](http://dev.measuremyho.me/#services). Click on one of the first two images to see this problem.

For reference, my images are 640x480 pngs.

What steps can I take to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your [style.css](http://dev.measuremyho.me/stylesheets/style.css) file you have the famous [box-sizing](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) css rule

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -o-box-sizing: border-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

which seems to be messing the (old version of) fancybox layout : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2d9vv7v/)**

The workaround is to revert `box-sizing` to `content-box` for fancybox elements only so apply this css rule after your general `box-sizing` declaration :

```
#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-wrap *{
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
      -o-box-sizing: content-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
         box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2d9vv7v/1/)** fixed

**NOTE** : This only apply to fancybox v1.3.x and lower. Fancybox v2.x doesn't have this issue.

Comment: That did it. I take it that this is fixed in fancybox v2?

Comment: @AmazingHorse : as far as I know fancybox 2 doesn't have this issue

Comment: Perfect. One addition, depending on the situations (like fancybox used in Readily WordPress theme), #fancybox-wrap can be .fancybox-wrap.

Comment: @SoumyabrataGhosh : bear in mind this issue is only presented in fancybox v1.3.x where the proper selector is `#fancybox-wrap`. On the other hand, the `.fancybox-wrap` selector is used in v2.x, which doesn't present the issue as in the OP. Most likely the theme you refer is using fancybox v2.x so you don't have to worry about applying this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

fix body margin right for FancyBox 2 and Bootstrap 3

```
    $(function(){   
    $("a.zoom").fancybox({
        beforeShow  : function() {
            document.onmousewheel=document.onwheel=function(){ 
                return false;
            };
            document.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll",function(){return false},false);
            document.onkeydown=function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode>=33&&e.keyCode<=40) return false;
            }
        },
        afterClose  : function(){
            document.onmousewheel=document.onwheel=function(){ 
                return true;
            };
            document.addEventListener("MozMousePixelScroll",function(){return true},true);
            document.onkeydown=function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode>=33&&e.keyCode<=40) return true;
            }
        },      
        prevEffect  : 'none',   // this is not important 
        nextEffect  : 'none',   // this is not important 
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'over'    // this is not important
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 80,   // this is not important 
                height  : 80    // this is not important 
            },
            overlay : {
                locked : false  // !this is important!
            }           
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer didn't completely fix the problem in my case, but indeed served as a starting point. I ended up with the following rules:

```
#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-outter, #fancybox-content {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
      -o-box-sizing: content-box;
     -ms-box-sizing: content-box;
         box-sizing: content-box;
}
#fancybox-content > div {
  margin-top:    -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

*Reverting* box-sizing for all elements inside `#fancybox-wrap` would break Bootstrap3 layout, so I did the reverting a little more selective.

And, for some reason, there was a blank space between both the top and bottom borders and the content, which was fixed with the margin rules. I don't know if it applies to all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue..

put this in your stylesheet.

.fancybox-inner img{

```
max-width: 100%;
```

}