# How do I turn on autoscaling in FancyBox, and why is this weird title thing happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

So my first question is how do I tell FancyBox to auto scale when a gallery is open, based on the size of the browser. I am currently using these jQuery settings and it is not working:

```
$("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
            'titlePosition'     : 'over',
            'fitToView'         : true,
            'overlayShow'       : true

        });
});
```

And I also would like to know why this bizarre thing is happening with the title box. I apparently 10 reputation points to post images so here is a link to the screenshot of the problem. http://puu.sh/cHg9h/d440778c01.png 
It is the little ligature thing coming off of the bottom right hand corner. It does the same with the title 'inside' setting. Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using fancybox v1.3.4? if so `fitToView` is not a valid option. Regarding the `title` thing, check if you are not falling under the following scenario http://stackoverflow.com/a/19921314/1055987